# Titanium android application crashes on First open from kitkat onwards

Tags: android, crash, titanium

I have developed an android application using Titanium sdk 3.5.1.The modules used in application are: LocationServiceModule and PushSubscription module. The problem is that ,in some devices the application continously crashes and restart the application.Mainly this issues are noticed in kitkat and loolypop.But it is not severe in jellybean:  The exception on the console is is:

`Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xc in tid 28820 (KrollRuntimeThr`)

Comment: Does the application crashes on startup or on the same place somewhere else ? I think you have to strip out parts of your application to find the actual problem.

Comment: also try to remove the modules used and check if error is persistent or not.